# Oracle - Zombie Table

Tags: sql, oracle, database-administration

I'm having this odd problem since yesterday. I've tried several options and I actually reinstalled ORACLE and the DB itself.

Here's the problem: I have this table that is somekind of zombie. Here are the symptoms:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM USER_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME='MYTABLE'
```

Returns a record, meaning that the table exists.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MYTABLE'
```

Returns all the columns of MYTABLE. So far so good, the table exists.

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE
```

Returns **ORA-00942: table or view does not exist**.
At this point I'm quite confused: the table seems to exist on the USERTABLES but I cannot SELECT over it?

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE (Foo NUMBER) TABLESPACE MYTABLESPACE
```

Returns:
**ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-00001: unique constraint (SYS.I_OBJ2) violated**

I do not understand this error. But the best is yet to come.

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE
```

Surprisingly, the above query (an exact copy of the 3rd query) returns several records now!
Moreover, I noticed that the column Foo is not present: the table I now see is my initial table that had other columns.

```
DROP TABLE MYTABLE
```

I now try to drop the table and I get the following errors:

**ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06512: at line 19**

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE
```

More confused than ever, I try the above query and, surprise surprise, the table no longer exists.

I don't undestand this: the table is on USERTABLES but I cannot SELECT over it, however, if I create a new table with the same name, I get an error but now I can SELECT over the previous version of that table with several records.

Any thoughts ? I really need your help :(

**EDIT** - I checked now: I'm unable to drop ANY table. This might just be a new symptom.

**Solution**

The problem was that MDSYS.SDO_GEOR_SYSDATA_TABLE table was missing and a drop event trigger was trying to access it, generating the error. The solution was restoring that table.

Comment: It sounds like you need to take a look at the real table -- avoid the possibly synonym issue, etc. So when you run the query to see if the table exists, who are you connected as? Is it a regular user, or system, or what? Select OWNER, TABLE_NAME in the first query. And try to specify the full name, as in OWNER.TABLE_NAME to see if what you THINK is happening is really what is happening.

Comment: Are you 100% certain it is _exactly_ `'MYTABLE'` and not `'MyTable'` or anything like that.

Comment: @MJB Good point, but I've already tried that. USER_TABLES has no OWNER column, but ALL_TABLE has. I checked the OWNER on ALL_TABLE and I'm connected using that user. I've also tried specifying the full name but no luck.

Comment: @Ben Yes, sadly I'm :( I'm using Toad, and I write the SELECT * query, run it and catch the error. Next I Ctrl+left click on the mouse on the table name and I can see the columns, scripts, grants, etc... What I'm trying to say is that I'm using the exact same name throug Toad to SELECT * the table and SELECT the USER_TAB_COLUMNS table.

Comment: also, "actually reinstalled ORACLE and the DB itself" what does that mean: reinstall and restore or reinstall and rebuild from script or import? If restore any corruption in the DB will be restored too

Comment: Sounds like a permissions issue. I've seen this many times where the querying user doesn't have SELECT permission on the table/view/whatever. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

If have privileges, try this query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM dba_objects
 WHERE object_name = 'MYTABLE';
```

And see what objects exist with that name. It might point you in the right direction.

Comment: The result of that query returns two records. There are two different tables with that name for two different owners (one of which is the one I'm connected with, but I can't drop the other table either). I was expecting that (two tables with same name for different owners), no surprise here. Any more ideas

Answer (score 1):

You didn't qualify the schema names when trying to select and drop. The CURRENT_SCHEMA of your session may be different form the log-on user. Check by trying

```
select SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'CURRENT_SCHEMA') from dual;
```

Instead of describing what the output was, could you please copy/paste the complete output for us?

Lastly, can you exclude that someone messed up the dictionary? You know, SYSDBA can do anything....

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've discovered the problem. MDSYS.SDO_GEOR_SYSDATA_TABLE table was missing, and a drop event trigger was trying to access it.