# Oracle - Unable to drop tables

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, ora-00942, drop-table

This question is related to the [one I posted yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9828609/oracle-zombie-table) but with further implications.

The situation is: I'm unable to drop *ANY* table. Here's an example:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE FOO (BAR NUMBER) TABLESPACE SYSTEM
 /
Table created.

SQL> SELECT COUNT(1) FROM FOO;
  COUNT(1)
----------
         0

SQL> DROP TABLE FOO;
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06512: at line 19
```

So, the table seems to exist but I'm not capable of dropping it.

Notice the error **ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1**. If I try to drop a non existing table, this error does not appear:

```
SQL> DROP TABLE NON_EXISTING_TABLE
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Somehow, the system is unable to find the table at *dropping time*.

The oracle installation and the DB itself is new (one day old).

EDIT - I retried this test using another tablespace and user (I just created ones) and I got a slightly different behaviour: using `SYS`, after I got the `DROP` error **I can still SELECT** from the table. However, using this new user, after I got the `DROP` error, **I no longer can SELECT** from the table.

**Solution**

We found the problem: the MDSYS.SDO_GEOR_SYSDATA_TABLE was missing, preventing the drop operation.The solution is to restore that table. Here is the complete solution, by **Gaurav Soni** (by the way, many thanks).

Run the script catmd.sql (located in $ORACLE_HOME/md/admin dir).

The catmd.sql script is the script that loads all objects needed by Oracle spatial in the database. Then drop the user.

you can also refer to oracle metalinks

[Steps for Manual Installation of Oracle Spatial Data Option](https://metalink.oracle.com/metalink/plsql/showdoc?db=NOT&id=110217.1&blackframe=1)

[Dropping user results in ORA-942 against SDO_GEOM_METADATA_TABLE](https://metalink.oracle.com/metalink/plsql/showdoc?db=NOT&id=303975.1&blackframe=1)

Comment: which oracle version have you installed? [link](http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_00604_error_occurred_and_recursive_sql_level_string.htm)

Comment: Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production

Comment: A bit of a long-shot, but it acts like there's something else occurring here.  Could there be a DROP trigger on DATABASE or your current schema?

Comment: I've checked that but I don't really know how to interpret that. I have the following drop triggers. AW_DROP_TRG on SYS. SDO_DROP_USER, SDO_GEOR_DROP_USER, SDO_NETWORK_CONS_DROP_TRIG, SDO_NETWORK_DROP_USER, SDO_NETWORK_UD_DROP_TRIG on MDSYS. Any suspect?

Comment: `select owner,trigger_name,trigger_type,triggering_event
      from dba_triggers
     where table_name ='FOO'
      AND trigger_type like '%EVENT'
      and triggering_event like '%DROP%'
     order by 1,2
     /`  Can you provide the output of this query

Comment: Sure, but no rows are returned from that query.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest that you activate SQL tracing (`ALTER SESSION SET SQL_TRACE=TRUE;`) and try the drop again.  This will generate a trace file on the server (in the `udump` directory) that will show all the SQL the session executed, including recursive statements.  This should show you the recursive SQL statement that is failing.

Comment: Using your suggestion and Gaurav's I was able to narrow it down: the problem is with the MDSYS.SDO_GEOR_DROP_USER trigger, most precisily with the SDO_GEOR_SYSDATA_TABLE that doesn't seem to exist! I tried to select over that table and I get a "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist". Then I edited the trigger to return before using that table, now I can drop tables. Next, and finally, I reedited the trigger to return immediatly after using that table and I no longer can drop tables. The table does not exist or cannot be found. Any ideas on why?

Comment: No idea.  That's related to Oracle's Spatial Option, I believe, which I don't have any experience with.  It might be that there was an error during the installation process.  If you're not using this option, best thing is to remove it.

Comment: Many, many thanks. I've asked my coworkers the creation script for this table. Now I have the table and I'm finally able to drop tables. However, I'm still curious about how this happened.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you created the table on system tablespace. You should create it on the user tablespace or create one to store your data.

Comment: As I said on the EDIT part of my question, I tried with a different user and tablespace.

Comment: I don't know of any general reason why this would prevent dropping of the table.  I can create and drop tables in my `SYSTEM` tablespace.